# How to fetch the value of all XML tags inside a parent XML Tag using Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, xml, regex

```
I have an XML like this:
<Machines>
<Machine>
<Machine_Name>Mac Book Pro</Machine_Name>
<Machine_Type>Laptop</Machine_Type>
<Outputs>
<Output>
<Hour>1</Hour>
<Speed>Very Quick</Speed>
</Output>
<Output>
<Hour>2</Hour>
<Speed>Quick</Speed>
</Output>
</Outputs>
<Capacities>
<Capacity>
<Hour>1</Hour>
<Speed>50%</Speed>
</Capacity>
<Capacity>
<Hour>2</Hour>
<Speed>30%</Speed>
</Capacity>
</Capacities>
</Machine>
<Machine>
<Machine_Name>LG Desktops</Machine_Name>
<Machine_Type>Personal computers</Machine_Type>
<Outputs>
<Output>
<Hour>1</Hour>
<Speed>Fast</Speed>
</Output>
<Output>
<Hour>2</Hour>
<Speed>Moderate</Speed>
</Output>
</Outputs>
<Capacities>
<Capacity>
<Hour>1</Hour>
<Speed>30%</Speed>
</Capacity>
<Capacity>
<Hour>2</Hour>
<Speed>10%</Speed>
</Capacity>
</Capacities>
</Machine>
</Machines>


This is the regex i tried "<Capacity>(?<Value>[\d\w\s\W\D]*)<\/Capacity>"
```

but what i get is all tags that lie between the first occurence of  to last occurrence of  that is i get all tag: output,hour,speed,machine_name(i get hour and speed for both output and capacity).From this i want to fetch the value of tag (Speed) that falls under (Capacities). that is I need to measure the speed capacity of machine every hour for particular machine type and compare it with previous hour's speed and find out the increase or decrease in the speed and generate report accordingly.

```
Can anyone please tell an accurate regex to fetch such data and I m strictly instructed to use regex to get these data I am not suppose to use XMLDocument so please kindly suggest me a regex i badly need it.
```

Comment: Try parsing the XML instead.

Comment: If this is school assignment, you should say so. It's an unusual requirement not to use proper XML utility classes.

Answer (score 1):

Once again, consider to parse XML using anything else but regexp, but check if that can help you:

```
string reg = @"<(?'tag'\w+?).*>" + 
             @"(?'value'.*?)"    +  
             @"</\k'tag'>";
string xml = "<test>this is the inner text</test>"; 
Match mMatch = Regex.Match (xml, reg);
```

Then you can use the property "Groups" to fetch data.

Source: 10 secs of google

Comment: It produces an error saying "Unrecognized Grouping Construct". I used while(mMatch.Success){ string matchfound+=mMaalue; mMatch = mMatch.NextMatch();}. what things do I need to replace?

Comment: I replaced it like this string reg = @"<(?Capacity\w+?).*>" +
                 @"(?<Speed[^>]*?>(?<Value1>.*?)</Speed>.*?)" +
                 @"</\Capacity>";

Comment: mMatch.Groups["value"] should return "this is the inner text"

Comment: but will it return any value if the string is like this:<test><test1>1st test</test1><test2>2nd test</test2></test> then will this regex work and will mMatch.Groups[value] return "<test1>1st test</test1><test2>2nd test</test2>?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Regex, use a real xml parser. For example, using [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

```
var speeds = XDocument.Load(fname)
             .XPathSelectElements("//Capacity/Speed")
             .Select(x => (string)x)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: yes i know its the most easiest way but i am helpless because i am very strictly instructed to use regular expression only. I am firmly warned to accomplish this task only by using regex. Please help me out

Comment: @user2786794 Show them this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags who instructed to use regular expression

Comment: I know its obvious to get frustrated but its matter of my job so i cant just argue got to do as instructed. Hope i get an answer or they change their mind